# Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards error

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a snakemake srcipt like

```
# minimal example
configfile: "../snakemake/config.yaml"
import os



rule generateInclude: 
    input: 
        archaic_inc=config['input']['archaic_include'], 
        modern_inc=config['input']['modern_include']
    output: 
        all_include='include_{reference_genome}.bed'
    params:     
        reference_genome='{reference_genome}'

    shell: 
        """
        if [ {params.reference_genome}=='hg19' ]; then
            bedtools intersect -a <(zcat {input.archaic_inc} | sed 's/^chr//') \
                -b <(zcat {input.modern_inc} | sed 's/^chr//') > {output.all_include}
        else
            bedtools intersect -a <(zcat {input.archaic_inc}) \
                -b <(zcat {input.modern_inc}) > {output.all_include}
        fi
        """
rule all: 
    input: 
        'include_hg19.bed'
```

When I run it, snakemake report

```
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.
```

I am not sure whats wrong with it, could your please gave me some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default snakemake uses the first rule as the target rule. By moving rule `all` to the top, you should be able to run this file:

```py
rule all: 
    input: 
        'include_hg19.bed'

rule generateInclude:
    ...
```